# ResourceClient hanging on LockSupport.park() on SunOS when connecting to Restlet Server

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

I have a very simple Restlet server that I'm testing with a very simple Restlet client, all using Restlet-2.1.0 with the following extensions:  xstream-1.4, jettison-1.3.

Everything works well on my Mac, but when trying to run this on SunOS 5.10, the client hangs when connecting to the server.  I can get a response when hitting the server from a browser, or from telnet, and also this same client works fine when connecting to any *other* resource other than the Restlet server.

Looking at the thread dump I see this:

```
"main" prio=3 tid=0x08070800 nid=0x2 waiting on condition [0xfe0eb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0xbbe827e8> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:969)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1281)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
        at org.restlet.engine.connector.ClientConnectionHelper.handle(ClientConnectionHelper.java:517)
        at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:180)
        at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:284)
        at com.redprairie.task.common.TempClient.main(TempClient.java:17)
```

I tried using both ClientResource.get() and Client.handle(Request) and both hang.

Server code:

```
server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, SERVER_PORT, TestServerResource.class);
Context ctx = new Context();
server.setContext(ctx);
server.start();
```

Client code:

```
Request request = new Request(Method.GET, "http://localhost:8188/retrieve");
Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
Response response = client.handle(request);
response.getEntity().write(System.out);
```

Resource:

```
public class TestServerResource extends ServerResource {

  private static volatile Customer bernard = Customer.createSample();

  @Get("json")
  public Customer retrieve() {
    System.out.println("GET request received");
    return bernard;
  }
}
```

The xstream and jettison extensions work perfectly to convert java objects to JSON and vice versa, and again, this works fine on my Mac OS X, but hangs on Sun...

I am new to Restlet so perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but these are simple examples taken from available documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to this issue: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/669#issuecomment-9174819

However that wouldn't explain why the server doesn't reply to restlet but does to others.
Are you having any exception on the server? I have a similar case and I actually got this exception on the server:

```
The connection was broken. It was probably closed by the client.

org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.blockWritable(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.AbstractGenerator.blockForOutput(AbstractGenerator.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:101)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at org.restlet.representation.StringRepresentation.write(StringRepresentation.java:237)
    at org.restlet.representation.CharacterRepresentation.write(CharacterRepresentation.java:76)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.writeResponseBody(ServerCall.java:509)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerCall.sendResponse(ServerCall.java:453)
    at org.restlet.ext.jetty.internal.JettyCall.sendResponse(JettyCall.java:312)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ServerAdapter.commit(ServerAdapter.java:196)
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:153)
    at org.restlet.ext.jetty.JettyServerHelper$WrappedServer.handle(JettyServerHelper.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:894)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:948)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think our situations are different.  I tried their solution of setting the max sleep and idle times and it made no difference.  Also I'm not getting any exceptions in the server.  It's just hanging...